# Segmentation fault- queue won't initialize

Tags: c, linked-list, initialization, queue, singly-linked-list

The above code throws a segmentation fault and I am racking my brain to see where it is. The queue doesn't get initialized. I have been looking at the code for the longest time and i cannot identify what is going wrong.

```
typedef struct node node;

struct node
{
int data;
node *link;
};

typedef struct list
{
node *head;
node *tail;
int number_of_nodes;
}s_list;

typedef struct queue
{
s_list *ptr_list;
}queue;

void list_initialize(s_list* ptr_list)    //debugger says this line is a problem? But seems fine to me?
{
    ptr_list->head=NULL;
    ptr_list->tail=NULL;    
    ptr_list->number_of_nodes=0;
}
void queue_initialize(queue* queue_list)
{
list_initialize(queue_list->ptr_list);
}
int main()
{
queue queue;
queue_initialize(&queue);     //Have used a debugger and this isn't succesfull.
}
```

I cannot change the variable names or structures because this is part of an assignment i am supposed to fill.

I have tried changing the queue_initialization function to:

```
void queue_initialize(queue* queue_list)
{
    queue_list=malloc(sizeof(queue));
    list_initialize(queue_list->ptr_list);
}
```

There is still a segmentation fault

Comment: You've answered your own question with the statement "The queue doesn't get initialized." - you need to initialise before you can call `list_initialize`

Comment: Using malloc for the queue initialization does not work too

Comment: It is a very poor programming practice to give a variable the same name as the type of that variable.   Suggest: `queue myQueue;`

Comment: The value `NULL` not defined.  The posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stddef.h>`, which is normally included in `stdio.h`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ptr_list is never initialized so in list_initialize() you are writing to random memory.  In queue_initialize() you need something like this:

```
void queue_initialize(queue* queue_list)
{
    queue_list->ptr_list = malloc(sizeof(s_list));
    list_initialize(queue_list->ptr_list);
}
```